# Roofing nails through 95 year old tongue/groove soffits

Tags: roofing, nails, soffit

I just had my 95 year old house painted and re-roofed. Is this acceptable? I’ve read that the nails need to be so long- but this is crazy! My shingles aren’t 95 years old- and didn’t have this problem when it was last reroofed.  So sad for these little pieces of history. 
What can be done?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A good contractor would've seen this coming and discussed it with you. Not much boils my blood like that kind of apathy from a "professional". Sorry you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how far up your roof is, if you paint it you probably won't notice the nails penetrating.

This is fairly common when there is no decorative soffit and just the underside of non plywood sheathing.  Yours did look surprisingly good before. I've never seen one that didn't end up looking like a bed of nails but the ones I see have typically been painted since the nails went in and while visible have a similar character to the un-sanded, partially peeled paint that was painted overtop on a lot of your woodwork (old, looking decent but missing finer detailing/workmanship).

Comment: In my area on the coast the nails are required to penetrate the decking. This reduces the chance of the nail backing out as I understand it.

Comment: Required by code, or required for warranty? If the latter, that should be up to the homeowner (and the roofer should've asked). If the former, the roofer should've at least mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

How long are the nails? Are they in enough material to hold? I assume so, based on 95 years of shorter nails.

I'd get up there on a ladder and cut the nails flush with an oscillating tool.

Then repair any wood damage and repaint.

[image: Oscillating Tool]

Comment: *Is this acceptable?* Sometimes it's par for the course. So is cutting them off and hitting it with some paint before the homeowner notices....

Comment: I would not use an oscillating tool--it'll take forever with THAT many nails. Perhaps a grinder or Sawzall with metal blade would be faster. Either way, I'd hate to be the one doing this job on a ladder with wasps 'checking me out' or a stiff breeze in 30deg weather. ;)